# Xamarin android app seems to be not working in release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using XF and whenever I'm creating apk package in release mode ,app gets deployed successfully and take me to login page but nothing happens when i tap on login button. The same is working if i run my app in debug mode. I also go through the device logs but didnt find anything specific.
Attached the logs.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    opupWindow
V/WindowManager( 2937): Window{421acbe8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyg
uard=false
D/InputReader( 2937): Input event: value=0
I/InputReader( 2937): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] wh
en=5072263116000
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
D/GestureDetector( 3907): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1
mTouchCnt : 8 mFalseSizeCnt:0
E/SamsungIndiaKeypad( 3907): ET9KDB_ProcessKey : 7
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=316 Removed QopupWindow (5/6)
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=316 Removed QopupWindow (-2/6)
V/WindowManager( 2937): Window{421acbe8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyg
uard=false
D/InputReader( 2937): Input event: value=1
I/InputReader( 2937): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.42
4 ] when=5072713039000
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=317(146) createSurf 0x400faccc (180x216),1 flag=4, Q
opupWindow
V/WindowManager( 2937): Window{421acbe8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyg
uard=false
D/InputReader( 2937): Input event: value=0
I/InputReader( 2937): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] wh
en=5072805118000
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
D/GestureDetector( 3907): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1
mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
W/ContextImpl( 2937): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified
 user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1323 com.android.server.InputMethod
ManagerService$5.run:2283 java.lang.Thread.run:856 <bottom of call stack> <botto
m of call stack>
W/ContextImpl( 2937): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified
 user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1337 com.android.server.StatusBarMa
nagerService.sendNotification:181 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.rem
oveNotification:816 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotifica
tionLocked:1570 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotification
:1643
D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService( 2937): sendNotification(3) - 17040994
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] turnOff:: id = 4mIsIDUsingPatternLED = true
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] setSvcLedStateLocked:: id = 4, color = 0, mode
= Off, set = Off
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] ForcedSvcLEDTask is running.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18898): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] setSvcLedLightLocked : mSvcLedState : 0x0  prio
rity : 6  mSvcLedMode : 0
D/IconMerger( 3159): overflowShown = false
D/IconMerger( 3159): moreRequired = false
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18898): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=317 Removed QopupWindow (5/6)
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=317 Removed QopupWindow (-2/6)
V/WindowManager( 2937): Window{421acbe8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyg
uard=false
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18898): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18898): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/GestureService( 3597): serviceOnOffReceiver: onReceive - ResponseAxT9Info
V/GestureService( 3597): disableService!!!!
W/ContextImpl( 2937): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified
 user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1337 com.android.server.StatusBarMa
nagerService.sendNotification:181 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.add
Notification:780 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.enqueueNotificati
onInternal:1293 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.enqueueNotificatio
nWithTag:1145
D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService( 2937): sendNotification(1) - 17040994
W/ContextImpl( 2937): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified
 user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1337 com.android.server.StatusBarMa
nagerService.sendNotification:181 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.rem
oveNotification:816 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotifica
tionLocked:1570 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotification
:1643
D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService( 2937): sendNotification(3) - 17040994
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] turnOff:: id = 4mIsIDUsingPatternLED = true
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] setSvcLedStateLocked:: id = 4, color = 0, mode
= Off, set = Off
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] ForcedSvcLEDTask is running.
D/LightsService( 2937): [SvcLED] setSvcLedLightLocked : mSvcLedState : 0x0  prio
rity : 6  mSvcLedMode : 0
D/GestureService( 3597): serviceOnOffReceiver: onReceive - ResponseAxT9Info
V/GestureService( 3597): enableService!!!!
E/GestureService( 3597): updateFlags started
E/GestureService( 3597): bVertical = false
E/GestureService( 3597): bHorizontal = false
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=300 Removed JnputMethod (3/5)
V/WindowManager( 2937): Window{421acbe8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyg
uard=false
V/GestureManager( 2937): onReceive GesutureActive :false
D/ProgressBar( 3159): setProgressDrawable mProgressDrawable = null, d = android.
graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable@437b9898needUpdate = false
D/ProgressBar( 3159): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 18
D/ProgressBar( 3159): setProgress = 0
D/ProgressBar( 3159): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
D/ProgressBar( 3159): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2466): id=300 Removed JnputMethod (-2/5)
V/WindowManager( 2937): Window{421acbe8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyg
uard=false
D/IconMerger( 3159): overflowShown = false
D/IconMerger( 3159): moreRequired = false
D/InputReader( 2937): Input event: value=1
I/InputReader( 2937): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.42
5 ] when=5073502627000
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
D/InputReader( 2937): Input event: value=0
I/InputReader( 2937): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] wh
en=5073592511000
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2937): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
D/GestureDetector(18898): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1
mTouchCnt : 6 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/dalvikvm(18898): GC_EXPLICIT freed 458K, 13% free 22561K/25832K, paused 1ms+2m
s, total 21ms
I/Choreographer(18898): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
h work on its main thread.
D/ProgressBar(18898): updateDrawableBounds: left = 468
D/ProgressBar(18898): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
D/ProgressBar(18898): updateDrawableBounds: right = 612
D/ProgressBar(18898): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
W/SignalStrength( 3304): Size of signalstrength parcel:56
W/SignalStrength( 3304): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 1046 99
22 200 22 200 -1 -1 -1 -1 2147483647 -1 0 cdma 0x0
W/SignalStrength( 3304): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 1046 99 -
22 -200 -22 -200 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 cdma 0x0
W/SignalStrength( 3304): initialize: SignalStrength: 22 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 214
7483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4
W/SignalStrength( 2937): Size of signalstrength parcel:172
W/SignalStrength( 2937): getGsmLevel=4
W/SignalStrength( 3352): Size of signalstrength parcel:176
W/SignalStrength( 3159): Size of signalstrength parcel:176
W/SignalStrength( 2937): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 22 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 214
7483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4)
W/SignalStrength( 3159): getGsmLevel=4
W/SignalStrength( 3159): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 22 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 214
7483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4)
W/SignalStrength(13748): Size of signalstrength parcel:176
W/SignalStrength( 3159): getGsmLevel=4
W/SignalStrength(10598): Size of signalstrength parcel:176
W/SignalStrength( 3159): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 22 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 214
7483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4)
W/SignalStrength(10598): getGsmLevel=4
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 3159): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=Si
gnalStrength: 22 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 214748
3647 gsm|lte 0x4 level=4
W/SignalStrength(10598): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 22 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 214
7483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4)
V/AlarmManager( 2937): waitForAlarm result :4
V/AlarmManager( 2937): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 3159): onReceive() - RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION, WIFI_ST
ATE, NETWORK_STATE
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 3159): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
D/IconMerger( 3159): overflowShown = false
D/IconMerger( 3159): moreRequired = false
D/BatteryService( 2937): update start
D/BatteryService( 2937): level:60, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true,
voltage: 3956, temperature: 305, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB power
ed:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303320, invalid charger:0, online:4, cha
rge type:1, current avg:460
D/BatteryService( 2937): Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController( 3159): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController( 3159): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar( 3159): NORMAL_BATTERY
D/IconMerger( 3159): overflowShown = false
D/IconMerger( 3159): moreRequired = false
```

Comment: Share your code what you write in that click event ?

Comment: I would suspect something is not working on the click event in release mode. I would add something like Insights to your application, wrap the code in a try catch and report anything that happens. Something will be failing somewhere and you have most likely buried the error in catch that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I had similar issues with conflicting reference versions. I referenced two different versions of System.Core in two different projects. Maybe check your references

Comment: I added a crash report and it says "system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent has no constructors"  when i tap on the login button. however I'm not sure why the same is not appearing in debug mode.In debug mode it works.?